# Netbeans and JDK 14

Tags: java, netbeans

The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation. 
I have jdk 14.0.1

Comment: Which NetBeans version are you using? What happened when you used `--jdkhome` to specify the location of the JDK?

Comment: version of netbeans- 8.0.2 and how to to use --jdkhome to specify location of th jdk as my new jdk version is 14.0.1

Comment: That won't work with Java 14. You will need to use NetBeans 11.3 if you want to use Java 14. `--jdkhome` is a command line parameter that you pass to NetBeans when you start it